# How to get image location to Label or Entry in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

in .xaml

```
<Image x:Name="image">
<Image.GestureRecognizers>
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="GetImageLocationFromExternalCard"/>
</Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
<Label x:Name="fileLocation"/>
```

in .xaml.cs

```
private void GetImageLocationFromExternalCard(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // what can i write is here
  image.Source = fileLocation.Text;
}
```

I want to make is like pick an image file from memory card and send as string location to label text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [MediaPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker?tabs=android)

```
var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync();
image.Source = photo.FullPath;
```